# Make an animated square with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make my "YellowTrack" var move, bu I'm getting crazy and i can't achieve it. I don't know why, but the "y" coordinate doesn't update, so It doesn't move. I've tried a lot of cases but any of them could solve the movement problen Could anybody help me? PD: Sorry for my bad code writing

The code is below:

```
function startGame() {

myGameLines1 = new DrawingLines(200, 0, 200, 600, "black");
myGameLines2 = new DrawingLines(350, 0, 350, 600, "black");
myGameLines3 = new DrawingLines(500, 0, 500, 600, "black");
myGameLines4 = new DrawingLines(650, 0, 650, 600, "black");
myGameLines5 = new DrawingLines(800, 0, 800, 600, "black");

myGameFinalLine = new FinalLine(100, 500, 800, 20, "purple");

myGameFixedSquare1 = new DrawingFixedSquares(171, 475, 60, 60, "yellow");  
myGameFixedSquare2 = new DrawingFixedSquares(321, 475, 60, 60, "red");
myGameFixedSquare3 = new DrawingFixedSquares(471, 475, 60, 60, "#F34621");
myGameFixedSquare4 = new DrawingFixedSquares(621, 475, 60, 60, "blue");
myGameFixedSquare5 = new DrawingFixedSquares(771, 475, 60, 60, "green");

myGameArea.start();


YellowTrack = new DrawingFixedSquares(171, 200, 60, 60, "yellow");

animate(YellowTrack, canvas, ctx, startTime);   

}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 1000;
    this.canvas.height = 600;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
},

clear : function() {
this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}       
}

  var ctx = myGameArea.context;
  var canvas = myGameArea.canvas;

        function DrawingLines(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {  

            this.x1 = x1;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;

            this.update = function(){       
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.lineWidth="2";
                ctx.strokeStyle="black";
                ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
                ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
                ctx.stroke();   
            }
        }



        function DrawingFixedSquares(x, y, width, height, color) { 
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.update = function(){
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }   

        }

        function FinalLine(x, y, width, height, color) {  

            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.update = function(){
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }


        function updateGameArea() {

            myGameArea.clear();
            myGameLines1.update();
            myGameLines2.update();
            myGameLines3.update();
            myGameLines4.update();
            myGameLines5.update();
            myGameFinalLine.update();
            myGameFixedSquare1.update();
            myGameFixedSquare2.update();
            myGameFixedSquare3.update();
            myGameFixedSquare4.update();
            myGameFixedSquare5.update();

            YellowTrack.update();
        }


        function animate(YellowTrack, canvas, ctx, startTime) {

            var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

            var linearSpeed = 100;

            var newY = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

            if(newY < canvas.height) {
              YellowTrack.y = newY;
            }


            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

              requestAnimFrame(function() {
              animate(YellowTrack, canvas, ctx, startTime);
            });
          }


          setTimeout(function() {
            var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            animate(YellowTrack, canvas, ctx, startTime);
          }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating things on a canvas is quite easy with window.requestAnimationFrame.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // Anonymous closure to sandbox my code
  void function() {
  
   // Tells the JS engine to use strict syntax rules
   // e.g. creating variables without var, let or const
   // creates an error in strict mode
   "use strict";
   
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var mouse = {x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
   var box = {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 20};
   var boxMoveSpeed = 25.0;
   
   // Called whenever the mouse moves 
   // (canvas.onmousemove can be used too)
   window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (canvas) {
     // Gets the canvas' offset from the top left of the screen
     var boundingRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
     
     mouse.x = e.clientX - boundingRect.left;
     mouse.y = e.clientY - boundingRect.top;
    }
   }
   
   // Game loop
   function loop() {
    // Tick (Update game logic)
    box.x += (mouse.x - box.x - box.width * 0.5) / boxMoveSpeed;
    box.y += (mouse.y - box.y - box.height * 0.5) / boxMoveSpeed;
    
    // Render
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(box.x,box.y,box.width,box.height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // Handy function that loops this
    // function at 60Hz (60 fps) for me.
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   // Called when the page finishes loading
   // I treat it like a 'main method' you see
   // in other languages
   window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
   loop();
   }
  
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```